# MVC - Getting route information

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have the following routes defined in global.asax

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Route1", 
    "Employee/List/{id}", 
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } 
);


routes.MapRoute(
    "Route2", 
    "Managers/List/{id}", 
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } 
);
```

When I got to
http://localhost/managers/list and http://localhost/employee/list, they hit the Index method on the Home controller as expected.

**I would like to generate a url based on the request data**

So if the current url is localhost/managers/list, I want to generate a url say

http://localhost/managers/list/3 (some id)

and if the current url is localhost/employees/list, I want to generate

http://localhost/employees/list/3 (some id)

I tried:

```
@Url.RouteUrl(new { controller = ViewContext.RouteData.Values["controller"], 
                      action = ViewContext.RouteData.Values["action"], id =  3})
```

but it always generates

/Employee/List/3

even when the url is managers/list.

**I am looking for the mvc way of doing this and not using Request.Url. Thanks.**

Comment: What's the point of the seemingly redundant routes?

Comment: two different urls to get to the same controller for seo purposes.

Comment: `RouteData.Values["controller"]` and `RouteData.Values["action"]` will return the name of the `Controller` and `Action` defined in the `RegisterRoutes` method, and will not parse the URL and extract the information from there, that's why you'll always get `/Employee/List/3`. You will need to use the  `Url.RouteUrl("Route Name", new {id = 3})` overload that allows you to specify the route name. You will need to Examine the `Request.Url` and determine the route name accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Well, your controller is always home, and action always index. So when you ask routing to make URL from it, it grabs first one that match - and that is Employee/List/{id}. 
You can not "force" it to use the second one. But if you are pretty sure that your route names will be solid and nice, you can use **RouteLink** instead of ActionLink (or Url.RouteUrl instead of Url.Action), and specify route name of route you want to use from generating URL.

```
@Url.RouteUrl("Route2", new { id = 3 })
```

Comment: also, look here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2808075/asp-net-mvc-route-to-url

Comment: How would I determine which route to use? It looks like I would need to read Request.Url (as suggested in the comment to my question above) for this.