# How to get default document for request?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, webforms

Asp.Net contains a mechanism to specify the default document in a web.config:

```
<defaultDocument>
    <files>
        <remove value="default.aspx" />
        <remove value="Default.asp" />
        <remove value="index.html" />
        <remove value="Default.htm" />
        <remove value="index.htm" />
        <remove value="iisstart.htm" />
        <remove value="landing.aspx" />
        <remove value="views.aspx" />
        <remove value="index.aspx" />

        <add value="landing.aspx" />
        <add value="views.aspx" />
        <add value="index.aspx" />
    </files>
</defaultDocument>
```

Is there a mechanism to retrieve the document that will be used for a certain local path request?

Requests could be: `/MySite/` (index.aspx), `/MySite/Views/One` (views.aspx), `/MySite/Pages/PageOne` (landing.aspx). Each directory contains a different "default document".

Comment: Have you tried wrapping them in location tags?

Comment: @Shawn I don't understand what that means. Can you elaborate?

Comment: Something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10045625/different-default-document-for-iis-sub-application I would assume you could just change the paths to /Mysite /MySite/Views/One, etc.

Comment: No I'll need to find the file name to do some rewriting by my app. I can't rely on Asp.Net to get it right. That's why my code need to detect what default page Asp.Net should have used.

Comment: Request.PhysicalPath gives you the file (on filesystem) that asp.net is trying to load. But I guess you want to get the document name before there is any request.

Comment: Maybe [`VirtualPathProvider`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.hosting.virtualpathprovider(v=vs.110).aspx) is a good point to look at.

Comment: If you are using MVC - check out [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2808075/asp-net-mvc-route-to-url) - it explains how to get from url like `/MySite/Views` to the `/MySite/Views/Index` by routes

Comment: @DarkWalker, I'm using ASP.Net forms.

Comment: Try this link

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/421778/asp-net-site-default-document-in-subfolder                                        http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732107.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Just add a Web.Config file inside each directory with the settings you want to override, in this case, with the defaultDocument settings